# Undefined type 'gnupg' class name error using VS Code with PHP and Intelephense extension

Tags: php, intellisense, vscode-extensions, php-extension, classname

Screen shot of the error in VS Code:

[image: VS Code Undefined Type Class Name]

Even with checking phpinfo() you will see gnupg installed and an active extension. The code will execute properly. But in VS Code you are given a fatal error and red underline when calling the class. A class that is supposed to be globally available.

I would like to correctly fix the problem and not just hide or ignore the red underline. Could not find a direct solution by searching the settings for anything related to "undefined type". Only the option to ignore "undefined type" error all together (not an option for me)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the proper solution scattered under various titles that tend to be too specific in request. Here I answer the question in a way that allows all languages being coded under VS Code to have easy access to a common error.

Location of the settings:

- File (menu) -> Preferences -> Settings
- Click inside the "Search settings" box and type in "stubs"
  [image]
- You will have to click on the Extension in the list to the left.
- Scroll down to the end of the list, there will be a button "Add Item".
- This opens up a menu to scroll another list and add any available extension (which provides the class).
- Do this for all extensions in your list (may have more or less in yours)